# Get all middle values between 2 numbers

Tags: algorithm, math

I want to get a middle value from 2 numbers, lets say the first number I have is >3 and the second number I have is <3 so 3 is a middle value here, and for instance I say first number is >5 and a second number is <3 so 3,4 & 5 should be the result. 
What is the suitable method for finding these values?

Comment: Are you looking for Round(Average)?

Comment: Are you using any programming language or the blackboard? Also what do you mean by middle value of 2 numbers :> maybe middle value of 3 numbers?

Comment: Your question is unclear: 10 is >3 and 2 is <3, but the "middle value" of 2 and 10 is not 3, it is 6 (assuming you meant the average)...

Comment: it offcourse means getting ALL the middle values that do not lie under those two number's ranges

Comment: In math, it is called *counting*. It all depends on your domain. Are you dealing with integers, real numbers, something else? Are you interested in a particular language?

Comment: What do you mean by `3, 4 & 5 should be the result`? You're looking for `a middle value`, implying that it is a single number. And what's with the less and greater than signs? The first number > 3 could be 10000 and the second < 3 could be 0. The middle (average) value is not 3 but 5000.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add both values and then divide them by 2. If you don't get an integer you can round up or down. If you give a language, you can get a snippet, but here is Java anyway:

```
int a = 2;
int b = 4;
int middleValue = Math.round((a+b)/2);
```

**EDIT**
After more details are added, the Java solution would look like this:

```
int start = 2;
int end = 6;
List<Integer> middleValues= new ArrayList<Integer>();

for(int i =start+1; i <= end; i++){
     middleValues.add(i);
}
```

Then your `middleValues` contain what you need.

If you are not dealing with integers, you can also use: `Math.floor(start)` and `Math.ceil(end)` in your loop conditions.

Answer (score 5):

To find the best middle value ( **Average** ) you can follow the next formula:

```
(x + y) / 2
```

in your example

> (3 + 3) / 2

Answer (score 0):

When using C or C++ you have to be careful because signed integer overflow is undefined. Starting with c++20 you can use [`std::midpoint`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/midpoint) to avoid all kinds of pitfalls.